# python: os.walk of e drive does not work

Tags: python, os.walk

Simple code:

```
import os 

filenamelist = []
#path = "E:\blah\blah\blah"
path = "C:\Program Files\Console2"
for files in os.walk(path):
    filenamelist.append(files)
    print files
```

The above works. But when I set path= "E:\blah\blah\blah" the script runs but returns nothing.

```
1) C:\Users\guest>python "read files.py"

('C:\\Program Files\\Console2', [], ['console.chm', 'Console.exe', 'console.xml', 'ConsoleHook.dll', 'FreeImage.dll', 'FreeImagePlus.dll'])

2) C:\Users\guest>python "read files.py"

C:\Users\guest>
```

Any idea why os.walk() is having a difficult time with E:\? I can't get it to read anything on E:. I have an external drive mapped to E drive.

Comment: good question. btw on linux the entire file system is walked with os.walk('/') but on windows I can only walk one drive at a time (C:\, D:\ etc)

Comment: If your path is E:\blah\blah\blah, you need to escape the backslashes before the B's.  Even if it isn't, it is good practice to escape them anyway.

Comment: I know you gave "E:\blah\blah\blah" as your example, but maybe some special characters in the real path are causing problems. Can you list the real path?

Comment: The real path is `path = "E:\madis\data\LDAD\mesonet\netCDF"`. But, I didn't `escape` the `path = "C:\Program Files\Console2"` and that worked.

Comment: @algotr8der That's because `\n` has meaning of a linefeed character. So, if you `print(path)` it would have line break in the middle. In `path` for C: you don't have such sequences, so python treats them as characters with no special meaning. To be on the safe side, it's better to always avoid having a single backslash in non-raw string literals (those that aren't prefixed with `r`), except for cases when you want to have an escape sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That could be because python treats `\` as an escape symbol and you have a combination that is really an escape symbol for E: disk path.

It might be solved in one of the following ways:

1. Raw string literals: `r"E:\blah\blah\blah"` (the backslashes are not treated as escape symbols).
2. Double-backslashes: `"E:\\blah\\blah\\blah"` (escape symbols are escaped by themselves).
3. Slashes `"E:/blah/blah/blah"` (this works on Windows too).